# Compiling modules for cross-compiled arm64 kernel fails with Syntax error

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation, make

I successfully cross-compiled the current Raspi Kernel on my 64-bit machine to the target architecture `arm64`. I went through all the necessary steps for inserting the newly built kernel into my [Dietpi](https://dietpi.com/) image. Now the only step left is cross-compiling the kernel modules into the target image. 
When I run

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/mnt/img modules_install
```

Sadly, this returns the following:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
  DEPMOD 4.14.79-v8+
```

What can I do about that?

Comment: I'm guessing that error wasn't fatal as `depmod` is still applied.  Does `/mnt/img/lib/modules/4.14.78-v8+` exist with content (directory w/ ~75 MB of modules) ?  The Pi kernel (as default configured) actually doesn't require any modules to boot (although it will not have wifi).  You can then tell whether any are available by checking `lsmod` -- if you see nothing, it hasn't found anything acceptable.  Otherwise you are probably okay.

Comment: @goldilocks Oh, wow, it doesn't need additional modules? That's great, I will try booting.

Comment: It doesn't *if* you applied one of the pi specific defconfigs properly.  Otherwise it may not boot at all, whether the modules built correctly or not. It's different from normal kernels in that because it is intended for a very specific piece of hardware, it doesn't need an `initramfs` containing a bunch of optional modules -- no kernel can access the stuff in `/lib/modules` until it has mounted the filesystem, and to do that it will require appropriate hardware drivers.  These are normally in the `initramfs`.  On the pi they are just built-in.

Comment: @goldilocks I remember, that I actually applied the proper defconfigs already. The device still won't boot, though.

Comment: @goldilocks Okay, seems like there was a file-system related problem when copying the kernel files from device to device. The original device installs the modules without any problem.

Comment: @goldilocks Good news: everything works now. I compiled it again and didn't copy it, but put it directly into the correct destination. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was to copy the compiled files to different devices instead of copying it directly from source to destination. The process is completed and everything works now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.